# Execute function multiple times or create stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

Assume I have a function like this

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.FinalScore desc) as Position, 
    T1.Employee, T1.FinalScore
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Position, Employee, AVG(Score) as FinalScore
     FROM 
         dbo.Answers
     WHERE 
         DATEPART(year, EvaluationDate) = @Year
     GROUP BY   
         Employee) as T1
```

This will return a table like such:

```
|--------|----------|-------|
|Position| Employee | FScore|
|========|==========|=======|
|   1    |   John   |  5.6  |
|   2    |   Tom    |  4.8  |
|   3    |   Paul   |  3.6  |
|   4    |   Mark   |  2.0  |
```

Now I need to create a tendency chart with the previous table, plus the information from previous years.

My question is, what is the best practice, should I call my function several times from my asp.net page to retrieve several tables, and handle the information on my page.

Or should I create a stored procedure that executes this function several times and inserts the data into a temporary table? Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TOP 
(
     Position int, 
     Employee nvarchar(60), 
     Score decimal(18,2)
)

DECLARE @Flag as int

SET @Flag = @Year - 3

WHILE (@Year > @Flag)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #TOP
       SELECT * 
       FROM dbo.MyFunction(@Year)

   SET @Year = @Year -1
END

SELECT * FROM #TOP
DROP TABLE #TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify your query to:

```
   SELECT row_number() over (order by avg(Score)) as position,
          Employee, AVG(Score) as FinalScore
   FROM dbo.Answers
   WHERE DATEPART(year, EvaluationDate) = @Year
   GROUP BY Employee;
```

Then, if you want this for all years, use `partition by`:

```
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by year(EvaluationDate) order by avg(Score)) as position,
          Employee, AVG(Score) as FinalScore
   FROM dbo.Answers
   GROUP BY Employee, year(EvaluationDate);
```

Comment: Well I did look before on the `partition by` clause, but its not suitable in my case, the actual date of the evaluations its not by year, I omitted it to simplify the query, there are 2 evaluations yearly by employee, one is done on july, but the 2nd its done on january of the next year. 

So i.e. for 2015 I have an evaluation in July/2015 and the 2nd is on January/2016

Comment: the simplified query for the function did helped, thanks!